# Firefox-Sync Data lost/not accessible

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

I just reset my Windows 8 and reinstalled Firefox 36. It logged in successfully but it has not synced any of my Old data. All my old bookmarks and passwords are lost. Firefox sync has logged me in with the same account but now it is syncing new data.
One more thing, I might have changed my device's name.
Any idea how can I get them back.